# JIRA Java REST Client returning 500 error

Tags: java, rest, client, jira

So I'm trying to set up a basic HTTP call to JIRA using the JerseyJiraRestClientFactory. I have all the dependencies in there and right now I have this...

```
public class SetUp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final NullProgressMonitor pm = new NullProgressMonitor();
        final Console console = System.console();

        if (console == null) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't get Console instance");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        String user = console.readLine("Enter your user name: ");
        char[] password = console.readPassword("Enter your password: ");
        char[] confirm = console.readPassword("Confirm password: ");

        while (!(new String(password).equals(new String(confirm)))) {
            console.printf("Error: Passwords do not match. Please Re-enter your password\n");
            password = console.readPassword("Enter your password: ");
            confirm = console.readPassword("Confirm password: ");
        }
        try {

        JerseyJiraRestClientFactory f = new JerseyJiraRestClientFactory

        System.out.println("\nafter 1");

        JiraRestClient jc = f.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(new URI(
                "my_server"), user, new String(password));
        System.out.println("\nafter 2");

        Iterator<BasicProject> r = jc.getProjectClient().getAllProjects(pm).iterator();

        System.out.println("\nafter 3");

        int count = 0;
        while (r.hasNext()) {
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println("\nafter 4");
        System.out.println("There are " + count + " issues.");
        user = "";
        Arrays.fill(password, ' ');
        }
        catch (com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.RestClientException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        }
    }
}
```

So this errors out right after it prints "after 2". I get this error code

"Exception in thread "main" com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.RestClientException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: Client response status: 500"

I've tried calling different methods and they all result in the same 500. I've also tried using different logins both valid and invalid, and they all 500. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Code 500 is an "internal server error", so that has nothing to do with your passwords.
( these should result in something like 401(Unauthorized) or 403(forbidden) )
Someone already asked a similar question in the Atlassian-Forum, please check here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/263719/using-oauth-and-the-jira-java-rest-client